# Creating simple tables in vim

Tags: vim, tabular, vim-tabular

Recently I've started discovering "deeper" vim and now I want to create a simple table without using any external plugins (I know it's bad, but I want to have some "know-how").
Let's say I want to have a table like this:

```
| name            | address                  | phone      |
|---------------------------------------------------------|
| John Adams      | 1600 Pennsylvania Avenue | 0123456789 |
|---------------------------------------------------------|
| Sherlock Holmes | 221B Baker Street        | 0987654321 |
|---------------------------------------------------------|
```

But how do I manage to make underscores till the end of the longest line and seperate columns with equal width? (In short way, no typing all by hand)

Comment: In case you change your mind and want to use plugins, then you might want to look into [vim-table-mode](https://github.com/dhruvasagar/vim-table-mode),[cucumbertables.vim](https://gist.github.com/tpope/287147) + [Tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular), or some [other plugins](https://vimawesome.com/?q=table).

Comment: @PeterRincker thanks, I know that one, but knowing what might be "under the hood" is also important for me ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the amount of the dashes needed then you can do:

```
{number}i-<ESC>
```

Where `{number}` is the amount of dashes needed. If you want to "learn" that automatically then you need to use VimL and `strlen()` function to first learn how many dashes are needed and then you can use `append()` to insert text below provided line.